# How to use a popover segue from a tableview prototype cell

Tags: uitableview, prototype, uipopovercontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to use a popover segue from a table view prototype cell.

It works fine if I use a modal segue but for some reason when I use a popover I get the following error:

Couldn't compile connection:  => categoryPicker => >

I can do it all through code but I'm wanting to use storyboards to do it.